# mutationobserver firing when no change and method not found issue

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I've placed an observer on an element using `MutationObserver`. In a one use case it works exactly as expected and fires after a change but in another user action where the element has not changed it appears to be firing - but in doing so it comes up with a method not found error, which doesn't appear in the first use case using the same observer.

The observer watches for an update within an element which gets updated with an image as a user selects an image.

In the working case a user selects an image from a list of images, it then updates and the observer fires - all great.
In the non-working case a user uploads an image - at this point though no update has happened to the target element (which is in view but below a colorbox.(not sure if that's relevant).

The firing itself would not normally be a problem but within the observer callback it calls a method which in the second case it says is not defined.
So in the first instance there are no errors but in the second instance:

I get an error `_this.buttons is not a function at MutationObserver.callback`

The code is being compiled with webpack

1. **1. Why is the observer firing** when the doesn't appear to the type of change being observed?
2. **Why does this error occur in this scenario** - when the method appears to exist and works as expected when there is a change?

Any help appreciated

here's the code - this class manages the actions for a page - I've removed some code to try and keep it brief (but still a bit lengthy - refactoring to be done):

**First, here's the code of the observer:**

```
const callback = (mutationsList, observer) =>{
            // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
            for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
                if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                    console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
                    module.buttons();
                    module.initialiseControls();
                }
                else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
                    console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
                }
            }
        };
```

**And here's the class** in which the observer method is contained.

```
export let fileImageWidgetControls = class {

    constructor({
                    previewBtn = '.preview-image',
                    addBtn = '#add-image',
                    replaceBtn = '#replace-image',
                    removeBtn = '#remove-image'
                } = {}) {
        this.options = {
            previewBtn: previewBtn,
            addBtn: addBtn,
            replaceBtn: replaceBtn,
            removeBtn: removeBtn
        }

        this.filemanager = new filemanagerHandler; //file selector class
        this.imageWidget = new updateWidget; //handles updating the image
        this.initialiseControls(); //sets up the page controls
        this.observer(); //sets up the observer


    }



    openFileManager =  () =>{
        //open colbox (which opens filemanager page
        //When filemanager loaded then initialise filemanager
        $(document).bind('cbox_complete', ()=>{
            console.log('Colbox complete');
            this.filemanager.init();
        });
        //handle colbox closing and update image in widget (if needed)
        $(document).bind('cbox_closed', ()=>{
            let selectedAsset = this.filemanager.getSelectedAsset();
            if(selectedAsset) {

                this.imageWidget.update(selectedAsset.filename);

            }

        });
        colBox.init({
            href: this.options.serverURL
        });
        colBox.colorbox()

    }

    remove = ()=> {
        //clear file and update visible buttons

        this.buttons();

    }
    /**
     * preview the image in a colorbox
     * @param filename
     */
    preview = function () {
        //open image in preview

    }
    /**
     * select image via filemanager
     */
    select =  () =>{

        console.log('select');
        this.openFileManager();

    }

    replace =  () => {
    //    image already exists in widget but needs replacing
        console.log('replace');
        this.openFileManager();
    }

    initialiseControls = () => {
        console.log('init controls');
        //preview button
        $(this.options.previewBtn).on('click', (e) => {

            e.preventDefault();
            this.preview();

        }).attr('disabled', false);

        $('#img-preview-link').on('click', (e)=> {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.preview();
        });

        // add button
        $(this.options.addBtn).on('click', (e) => {

            e.preventDefault();
            this.select();

        }).attr('disabled', false);

        //replace button
        $(this.options.replaceBtn).on('click', (e) => {

            e.preventDefault();
            this.replace();

        }).attr('disabled', false);

        //remove button
        $(this.options.removeBtn).on('click', (e) => {

            e.preventDefault();
            this.remove();

        }).attr('disabled', false);

        this.buttons();

    }
    //set an observer to watch preview image for changes
    observer= ()=> {
        const module = this;
        const targetNode = document.getElementById('image-preview-panel');
        const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
        const callback = (mutationsList, observer) =>{
            // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
            for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
                if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                    console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
                    module.buttons();
                    module.initialiseControls();
                }
                else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
                    console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
                }
            }
        };
        const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
        observer.observe(targetNode, config);
    }

    buttons = function() {

        let imagePreview = $('#image-preview');

        if(imagePreview.data('updated')=== true && imagePreview.data('updated') !== "false") {
            console.log('image present');
            $(this.options.addBtn).fadeOut().attr('disabled', true);
            $(this.options.removeBtn).fadeIn().attr('disabled', false);
            $(this.options.replaceBtn).fadeIn().attr('disabled', false);
            $(this.options.previewBtn).fadeIn().attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            console.log('image not present', imagePreview.data());
            console.log('image element:', imagePreview);
            $(this.options.addBtn).fadeIn().attr('disabled', false);
            $(this.options.removeBtn).fadeOut().attr('disabled', true);
            $(this.options.replaceBtn).fadeOut().attr('disabled', true);
            $(this.options.previewBtn).fadeOut().attr('disabled', true);
        }
    }
}
```

I copied code from a tutorial hence some of the comments until I refactor

Comment: Why are you using the class fields syntax? Per JS specification arrow functions can't use `this` of a class instance so their `this` is whatever it was at the time the method declaration was initially created. Use class methods.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the question. I think this is something I need to learn more about. I thought using the arrow function ensured `this` was referencing the main class? In this method I did also create a `const module = this;`.I've got the concepts wring here so going to do a bit more learning ... thank you

Comment: Managed to resolve, added a reference to this from within the nested function and works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `const module = this;` within the method and referenced that within the nested function and now pointing to the correct `this`